# A button clickable when conditions are met (Android Studio)

Tags: android, button, clickable

Is there a feature that I can make a button clickable only when a certain condition is met?

For instance, I can ask users to swipe 10 times, and only after users swipe 10 times, a button is clickable to receive an award.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the button (instead of disabled you can set isFocused = false):

```
button.isClickable = false
button.isEnabled = false
```

Add swipe-listener. Inside it increment a counter. After it becomes 10, set:

```
button.isClickable = true
button.isEnabled = true
```

Also inside a click-listener you can check the counter >= 10.